# Validating data from ajax injected elements. Need to bind new data to the document so the validation sees it. MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I need to validate form data that is injected by an ajax get.  The following form works fine as far as validation is concerned up to the point of adding new form elements.  I am using MVC 5 but believe this extends more to the scope of jQuery.

The Metadata validation classes:

**this works fine in form**

```
public class Exer_WorkoutMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is optional but testing now")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**This doesn't work because I believe I am not binding the ajax get correctly to the view**

```
public partial class Exer_RoutineMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Routing Name is Required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The following form works fine as far as validation is concerned up to the point of adding new form elements. Below is the main form I use.  At the bottom is the scripts I call to get a page, then call function to validate the form on submission.

```
<div id="AjaxUpdate"></div>
<div id="showFaliure"></div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 

    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Workout</legend>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr style="justify-content:center">
                    <td>
                        Workout Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { style = "width:100%" })@*<input type="text" name="Workout.Name" style="width:100%" />*@
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                      Description:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)  @*<input type="text" name="Workout.Description" /> *Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Exer_Routine[0].Name)*@
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Wrokout Notes:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Notes)
                    </td>

                </tr>
                   </table>
             <br />
            <div id="RoutineAndSetCounts">
                <input type="hidden" name="RoutineCount" value="0" />
                <input type="hidden" name="TotalSetCount" value="0" />
            </div>
            <div id="AddRoutine">Add Routine</div>
            <div id="RoutineRows">

              </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {


        $("#AddRoutine").click(function () {
            var routineCount = routineCount = $('input[name=RoutineCount]').val();
            **////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Get Data Here - How do I bind this data so that when the form is submitted 
            //it validates the data that was injected below??
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**
            $.get( '/Default/AddRoutineHTML?RoutineCount=' + routineCount, function(data) {
                $('#RoutineRows').append(data);
            });
            routineCount++;
            routineCount = $('input[name=RoutineCount]').val(routineCount);

        });
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // This Function works well on the original data, 
        //just can't get it to work on the injected data
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $('form').submit(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
            $form.validate();
            if ($form.valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/Default/NewWorkout',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                        alert('form was submitted');
                    }
                });
                evt.preventDefault();
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

**This is the /Default/NewWorkout data loaded into the main workout page.  I can't get this newly added data to bind correctly to the document so the document validation script sees it:**

```
<table>
        <tr style=" justify-content:center">
        <td>
            Routine Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            @*Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_Routine.)<input type="text" id="Workout.Exer_Routine[@ViewBag.RC].Name" name="Workout.Exer_Routine[@ViewBag.RC].Name" /> *@
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_RoutineList[Model.RoutineCount].Name)

        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Description:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_RoutineList[Model.RoutineCount].Description)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Notes:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_RoutineList[Model.RoutineCount].Notes)
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could re-validate all elements including new elements with:

```
var $form = $("form")
$form.removeData('validator')
     .removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
```

See also http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

Comment: Thank you! Worked!  Up voted and marked.  Do you by chance know how to get the validation to mark the fields (with the standard css i believe it borders it in red and adds the error message) individually as opposed to just the summary validation?  Summary validation works but would like to go a step further if possible.  Thanks again!